# sentiment analysis using SentiWordNet.

Tags: senti-wordnet

I want to classify sentences as positive, negative or neutral. I have got the code written in java but i am not understanding how to use the code for my file.In the above code where i should use my file and the results for each sentence should come as positive, negative and neutral. Please guide me for this.

```
public class SWN3 {
private String pathToSWN = "data"+File.separator+"SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
private HashMap<String, String> _dict;

public SWN3(){

    _dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String,     Vector<Double>>();
    try{
        BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
        String line = "";           
        while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] data = line.split("\t");
            Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-      Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
            String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
            for(String w:words)
            {
                String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                {
                    Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                    if(index>v.size())
                        for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                            v.add(0.0);
                    v.add(index, score);
                    _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                    for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                        v.add(0.0);
                    v.add(index, score);
                    _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                }
            }
        }
        Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)      {
            String word = (String) iterator.next();
            Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
            double score = 0.0;
            double sum = 0.0;
            for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
            for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                sum += (double)1/(double)i;
            score /= sum;
            String sent = "";               
            if(score>=0.75)
                sent = "strong_positive";
            else
            if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                sent = "positive";
            else
            if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                sent = "weak_positive";
            else
            if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                sent = "weak_negative";
            else
            if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                sent = "negative";
            else
            if(score<=-0.75)
                sent = "strong_negative";
            _dict.put(word, sent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
}

public String extract(String word, String pos)
{
    return _dict.get(word+"#"+pos);
}
```

}